# Non-English data insertion Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, utf-8

How to insert non-english data in Oracle. I have tried below code where before insertion the data is in Hindi.

```
Worker POJO class

@Column(name = "name", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR2(255)")
private String name;
//getter and setter

Insert
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
Transaction tx= null;

try { tx = session.beginTransaction();
Worker w = new Worker;
w.setName = "मनीषा";
System.out.println(w.getName()) // Prints the data in hindi
session.save(Worker);
}
tx.commit();
//Catch block
```

When I select the record from database, it shows "?????". I should get result as "मनीषा".  What wrong I am doing here.

```
Select
try { tx = session.beginTransaction();
String hsql = "from Worker";
Query query = session1.createQuery(hsql);
query.list(); // Prints ?????
}
tx.commit();
```

This is my db configuration file using hiberate 4.3.5. I have set utf-8 for non-english characters. How can I save and fetch hindi data using hibernate from oracle.

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">pass</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="connection.useUnicode">true</property>
        <property name="connection.characterEncoding">utf-8</property>
        <property name="connection.charSet">utf-8</property>
        <mapping class="com.dep.dao.Worker"></mapping>
```

Comment: You need NVARCHAR2 instead of VARCHAR2.

Comment: @FilburtTried with that also. It did not work. Same problem

Comment: what is the result of the following query: select value from sys.nls_database_parameters where parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET';

Comment: @tbone  WE8MSWIN1252

Comment: Character set  WE8MSWIN1252 does not support Devanagari, so you must use NVARCHAR2 - unless you migrate the character set of your database. Have a look at this document: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/global.htm#JJDBC28646